# Necesito obtener el dato en where en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Muy buenas Estoy haciendo una consulta usando group by pero yo necesito obtener un valor en where e intentando en algunas formas gracias por su comprension

```
select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles D 
inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto  group by NombreProducto
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estas son  las consultas que estoy realizando en where pero no sale como quiero :(

```
select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles D 
inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto where D.IdProducto=51  group by NombreProducto 

select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles D 
inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto where Cantidad=51  group by NombreProducto
```

Comment: y ¿cuál es ese resultado que quieres, como deseas que sea la salida?

Comment: La fila 11 y entre otros pero quiero llamarlo en una solo fila

Comment: edita y muestranos como estas intentando agregar el `WHERE` a cualquiera de las consultas

Comment: Algo asi ? Select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles D inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto where Cantidad=51 group by NombreProducto pero otro sugieren que usen having mmm

Comment: que resultado te da esa consulta???...puedes subir una imagen de tu diagrama?? con eso podremos verificar exactamente como lo estas haciendo...

Comment: Creo que tenes una confusion.. vos que queres traer exactamente? porque el 51 que ves ahi es el resultado de un count.. vos queres traer que cosa?

Comment: osea solo quiero q muestre una fila

Comment: la fila donde la cantidad es igual a 51? @SamuelG

Comment: si esa y tambien en algunas

Comment: y que te refieres con *en algunas*?

Comment: bueno amigos ya lo solucione era el having                                           
**select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles.D 
inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto  group by NombreProducto having COUNT(D.IdProducto)=51** de esta forma era gracias por su atencion

Comment: si esa es tu solución puedes publicarla como respuesta, explicarla y eventualmente puedes marcarla como aceptada de modo que sepamos que esa es la solución a tu pregunta.

Comment: Si amigo ya lo hice

Answer (score 1):

Bueno despues de tantos intentos 
La solucion fue asi:

```
select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles.D 
inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto  group by NombreProducto having COUNT(D.IdProducto)=51
```

Cuando se usa un dato agrupado ya no se usa el la clausula Where en su remplazo se usa el Having

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en la primera consulta que has hecho:

```
select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles D 
inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto where D.IdProducto=51  group by NombreProducto
```

si haces

> D.idProducto = 51

te dará el id que tenga ese numero, asi que por lo que has dicho esto no es lo que buscas...

---

respecto a la segunda consulta:

```
select P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad from Detalles D 
inner join Productos P on D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto where Cantidad=51  group by NombreProducto
```

tu error esta en

> where Cantidad=51

ya que el error te dará tal vez en el alias... seria bueno que cambies esa parte por

> where count(D.IdProducto) = 51

prueba hacerlo de esta forma:

```
select   P.NombreProducto,count(D.IdProducto) as Cantidad 
from     Detalles D, Productos P 
where    D.IdProducto=P.IdProducto and 
         count(D.IdProducto)=51  
group by NombreProducto
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda ya lo solucione y buen dato tienes mucha razon